# number to the number

Tags: idiomatic-language, slang

In "Breaking bad" the recorded answering machine says:

> Yo, yo, yo, 1, 4, 8, 3 **to the 3 to the 6 to the 9** representing the ABQ. What up, beyotch? Leave it at the tone.

What does "to the" mean in the phrase in bold?

Comment: ABQ= 2, 2, 7 on the dial face.

Comment: @Lambie The series takes place is Albuquerque.

Comment: @Acccumulation representing **the** ABQ** cannot refer to Albuquerque. It would be good to know the episode.

Comment: @Lambie Why not?

Comment: @Acccumulation Because it says: THE ABQ. We don't say **the Albuquerque** to refer to the name of that city,. That's why.

Comment: @Lambie If by " 'we' don't say 'the Albuquerque' ", you mean " 'The Albuquerque' is nonstandard", that's hardly an argument. The intent was not to present a "standard" greeting.

Comment: He would not have said "the Albuquerque" to refer to the city, per se.  No American English speaker would say that. It is not non-standard. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, it's a phone number, in this case 148-3369. But what I suspect you're really asking about is more of a formulation of

> X to the Y to the Z to the A

In this case, the message on the answering machine is emulating a common way of speaking in rap music (the "yo yo yo" is another hint). Consider Rapper's Delight, widely considered the first mainstream hip hop song (from 1979):

> I said a hip hop
>
> Hippie to the hippie

Or Jay-Z's So Ghetto for a more modern usage:

> M-to-the-A-baby-R-C-Y

He's just spelling "M-A-R-C-Y." The "to the" as well as the "baby" are just filler words. (blank) to the (blank) is kind of a sing-song, non-sense way of simply connecting two words, often two nouns. It's a stylistic choice rather than anything that adds meaning (aside from trying to make the speaker sound cool, that is). "3 to the 3 to the 6 to the 9" means nothing more than "3369."

Comment: There is no such number in the US numbering system for telephones. Numbers go: 1-xxx-xxxx, or without the 1. ABQ on the US dial face stands for 227.

Comment: @Michael W. Thank you for breaking it down! This was exactly what I was asking about.

Comment: Just a note that the usual way of saying the mathematical concept "X raised to the power of Y" is also "X to the Y", ie "2 to the 3 is 8".  Most definitely not what's meant here though.

Comment: @Lambie It doesn't sound like you are familiar with Jesse Pinkman.

Comment: @choster I saw every damn episode, are you kidding?? "Everybody" I know did. That said, I cannot explain the wording to my own satisfaction. Can you explain the whole thing? Cogently? Can you break bad here?

Comment: @Lambie In that case, you are aware that this is a fictional show, set in Albuquerque, and that Jesse affects hip-hop-inspired intonation and slang. "No such number" is irrelevant—the show would not risk another Tommy Tutone, and giving a Klondike 5 number would be a little precious. ABQ is common local slang for Albuquerque, not just the airport, as is also the case with DFW and ATL.

Comment: @choster OMG, I know all that! However, no AmE speaker would say: **the ABQ**", Check it out: https://www.bizjournals.com/albuquerque/news/2018/03/02/your-voices-what-you-said-an-abq-newcomer-can.html It's just ABQ I am not hung up on the hip-hop thing. I am hung up by the fact one cannot derive the structure of a US telephone number from the message: 1-(xxx) xxx-xxxx. There are  not enough numbers. Only "**the** Big Apple" for NYC takes a **the**. So, I ask you again, can  you actually explain it?? I have yet to see any decent explanation for the message.

Comment: @Lambie I am dumbfounded by the vehemence of your objection. *The* is perfectly natural, *especially* given the hip-hop influence. Most of the U.S. did not switch to 10-digit dialing until the 2000s, especially in places like New Mexico where there was only one area code.

Comment: @Labmie Are you from a populated area? Where I live, it's the same area code for 100 miles in any direction. While listing area codes has become more popular lately, the fact there's only one area code means that people and businesses often just omit the area code, giving only 7 numbers. In fact, New Mexico only has 2 area codes for the entire state, so I would hazard to guess that leaving off area codes is common there, too.

Comment: @choster My objection is to putting a "the" in front of the name of a city. It just ain't done. Hip-hop does not use "the" for cities. **Where did you ever get that idea**?

Comment: @MichaelW. Yes, I am in a populated area. But you must be missing **my** point. This: 1, 4, 8, 3 to the 3 to the 6 to the 9 does not translate to a US phone number. No phone number begins with 1 UNLESS you happen to mention it BEFORE the area code, AND " 4, 8, 3 to the 3 to the 6 to the 9" is not enough numbers, even locally. You need: three plus four numbers. As you said 7 numbers and no initial 1. So, I ask the question **again** what is the character's number?

Comment: @Lambie You're aware television shows aren't supposed to use actual numbers, right? No phone number starts with 555, either, but you're going to see that in a lot of entertainment media. Do you also have a problem with those numbers?

Comment: @MichaelW. Who is saying they have to use an actual number? The area code for Arizona is 505, I'm just saying in response to  you. It is not in the quote. But TV shows do use properly **structured** numbers all the time. And this one is not properly structured in terms of US telephone numbers.

Comment: @Lambie Why can you accept a phone number that starts with "555," but not one that starts with "1"? They are both impossible numbers, yet you only have an issue with one of them.

Comment: @MichaelW. I did not say anything about 555, you did. The NANP divides the territories of its members into numbering plan areas (NPAs) which are encoded numerically with a three-digit telephone number prefix, commonly called the area code.[3] Each telephone is assigned a seven-digit telephone number unique only within its respective plan area. The telephone number consists of a three-digit central office code and a four-digit station number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan [Read the entire page for all the rules,including no initial 1 in the actual number.]

Answer (score 1):

It's the person's phone number, without the first 3 digits : 148-3369.

Some people still say phone numbers like this, in areas with lots of small towns, where you know that everyone has the first three digits.

Comment: I have never heard that in the US. Ever. Also, ABQ=227

Comment: @Lambie You've never heard someone omit the area code?

Comment: @Acccumulation Of course, I have. But no numbers are structured as the responders claim. And personally, I cannot say exactly what it is,either.

Comment: @Lambie You're pot on for the ABQ (for Albuquerque, where the series is set, not 227 area code for Maryland :)
I've edited my comment to make it clearer.

Comment: @SamuelMartin The area code for Albuquerque is 505. **And**in the States, numbers begin with 1-[area code]-[xxx-xxxx]. Now, can you decipher the message? Because I have not been able to. :) But usually people do not use the 1. That said, on the dial face of the damn phones, ABQ stands for 227 but is not an area code. See for yourself: https://www.google.com/search?q=telephone+dial+face&oq=telephone+dial+face&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3667j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: ABQ stands for Albuquerque, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

i think its a phone number?? i know phone numbers used to have 3 numbers-4 numbers, instead of today's phone numbers that are 3 numbers-3 numbers-4 numbers.

Comment: On the one hand, that part of a telephone number - called the "central office code" - can't begin with a 1.  On the other hand, TV shows often intentionally use fake or impossible phone numbers.